# weird javascript object syntax: {}['constructor']

Tags: javascript, object, syntax, properties

Try these in your browser's JS console:

```
{}['constructor']                      //==>  ['constructor']
{}['constructor'] === ['constructor']  //==>  false
console.log({}['constructor'])         //==>  function Object() { [native code] }
```

The first expression evaluated returns an array with a single item: `'constructor'`, However, the second expression seems to contradict the first by returning `false`. The third logs the `Object` constructor to the console.

Why are the second two expressions not consistent with the first?

Comment: Try `[1] === [1]` to see why the second one is false. Each array literal is a different array.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Comment: The third one gets the object literal's `constructor` property...

Comment: @Ian I see that, but why doesn't the first?

Comment: And I don't think the second one has anything to do with arrays. `{}['constructor']` will be evaluated as an expression (which is what the third example shows). And obviously the constructor won't be equal to an array

Comment: @Ian Wrong - see my answer below. It just parses as an empty block, then the expression (which becomes false)

Comment: @Ian Not sure of the precedence, but the second might be parsed as `{} (['constructor'] === ['constructor'])

Comment: @Doorknob And where's your proof? You may be just as wrong, you shouldn't just claim stuff

Comment: @Barmar Very true, I'll have to look into that

Comment: @Ian The fact that putting an expression in the block changes nothing.

Comment: @Barmar uhh, that's what I just said :P

Comment: @Doorknob Sure it does. How do you know the block isn't interpreted as an object literal?

Comment: @Ian I just said that - putting in an expression changes nothing. Ex. `{var x = 5}['constructor'] === ['constructor']`

Comment: @Doorknob Oh, so I'm just supposed to believe you because you say so? Your example means nothing. No matter how `{var x = 5}['constructor']` is evaluated, it will never be equal to `['constructor']`, so it doesn't help your argument. As I'm testing it out more now, you seem to be right. But you have no reasoning or some sort of citation

Comment: @Ian How can you possibly thing that `{var x = 5}` is an object? Try `var obj = {var x = 5}` - error, of course.

Comment: @Doorknob Where did I say it's an object? The result of a block statement is the evaluation of its last statement. The result of `{a.push(1)}` is `1` (assuming `a` is an empty array). Therefore couldn't the result of `{a.push(1)}["constructor"]` be `1`'s `constructor`. It can't, but that's what I'm confused about

Comment: @Ian Okay, then explain why `{var x=5}['constructor']` evaluates to `['constructor']`

Comment: @Doorknob Exactly, at first, I thought that would make a different result but found out it's not as I expected. Note - I edited my last comment because I wrote it too fast and meant something else. But what I'm looking for is **why** is the behavior we're seeing happening? Why isn't it what I expect?

Comment: @Ian http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938829/weird-javascript-object-syntax-constructor?noredirect=1#comment26213131_17938861

Comment: @Doorknob Again, that's nice that you're claiming things, but I don't care for that. Why should we assume that first? Is it somewhere in the ES5 spec? Or is that some rule you just made up? I understand that's the behavior we're seeing, but I don't see why we should trust that. I can't find anything about this sort of thing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34421/discussion-between-doorknob-and-ian)

Comment: @Ian Ok, I'll find a reference

Comment: @Doorknob Again, I believe you, you've obviously proven that seems to be the behavior. I guess I'm just interested in the definition of that behavior and/or why it would be that way

Comment: @Ian Yes, in fact now **I'm** interested in that :P I am trying to find the specification for that, but it's hard to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because

```
{}['constructor']
```

Is being parsed as

```
{
    // empty block
}
['constructor']
```

Try typing

```
var x = {}; x['constructor']
```

Or

```
({})['constructor']
```

And you will get the expected result. `{}` is always parsed as an empty block, **except** where it wouldn't make sense (like in the two examples above).

[Barmar explains the second in the comments.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938829/weird-javascript-object-syntax-constructor/17938861#comment26212912_17938829) In short, `[1] !== [1]` because they're two different array objects.

The third example works because JavaScript knows that you can't pass a block to a function, so it assumes an empty object instead.

Comment: Try also `({})['constructor']`

Comment: It's starting to make sense now. Is there some sort of guide that says when `{}` will be parsed as an object vs. a block?

Comment: @Web Always a block - **unless** it doesn't make sense to have a block there.

Comment: I just got taught! :)